# Traveling from Ushguli to Batumi, Georgia in one day

Tags: transportation, georgia-country

I'll be trekking in Georgia in September from Mestia to Ushguli as a group of 4 people.

We have a flight booked back home departing from Batumi at Friday morning around 9:30 AM, while we're planning on finishing the trek at Wednesday evening, spending the night in Ushguli.

So what I'm trying to understand is - is it practical to plan on getting from Ushguli to Batumi in a single day? Maybe over the night? I know the drive between Batumi and Mestia could take up to 7 hours, so I figured that with a problematic bus schedule this could be tricky and might take two days.

Considering we don't mind taking a taxi to and/or from Mestia or even renting a car - how can we do it?

EDIT:

Alternatively, it is possible for us to **start** the hike 1 day earlier only if we could find a way to get from Batumi to Mestia while leaving Batumi at 5PM. That way we will have two full days for the distance at the **end** of the trek, described in the original question, making it much more feasible.
I'm guessing taxis are not hard to find in Batumi but will we be able to find a driver to take us there so late? Or a car rental to leave In Mestia and pickup 4 days later?

Comment: With a group of 4 people the most convenient will be to hire a taxi along with its driver, I think.

Comment: @alamar I'm sure, and we would like to take one. But we were wondering if it would be possible to find a driver willing to drive us for 6-7 hours, when the drive could end at 11PM. That be true either at the end of the trek or at the beginning of it.

Answer (score 2):

Two full days to make the move from Ushguli to Batumi is plenty, as you *should* be able to do it all in one day. Your cheapest option for four people is to use a bus. Keep in mind that you will need a taxi driver to take you from Ushguli back to Mestia, in order to catch a bus as [there is no public transport within Svaneti](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1902860-i33344-k10274783-Ushguli_to_Mestia_bus_on_a_Sunday-Mestia_Upper_Svaneti_Samegrelo_Zemo_Svaneti_Region.html) (no buses from Ushguli to Mestia).

In my experiences in other parts of Georgia, taxis are very easy to find and run 24/7 and are quite cheap. It's fairly easy to find a willing driver, who will take you far. Everything is negotiable and people are usually very friendly.

A taxi from Ushguli to Mestia is about $16-$20 USD. The bus from Mestia to Zugdidi is $9 USD and operates 3 times a day. The bus from Zugdidi to Batumi is $9 USD and also operates 3 times a day.

You can see [the full route here](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Ushguli/Batumi).

That website mentions:

> "Minibuses (marshrutkas) depart regularly, but there is no fixed
>   schedule. Pay with cash to the driver or at the station."

Also, there are usually a lot of taxi drivers near bus stations in Georgia, if you do not want to wait for a bus. A bus is definitely a little cheaper, but can take a while.

Alternatively, you could book a taxi (or a "bus taxi") directly from [this website](https://kiwitaxi.com/en/georgia/zugdidi-%3Ebatumi#transfers),  which costs between $120 USD to $200 USD. 
This is probably the easiest option but costs more money. The choice is yours.